# Create a cookie with javascript (got a whole cookie string already from Set-Cookie header)

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, session-cookies

I know this was asked before, but I have a little bit of a different situation:

I need to create a cookie with javascript with this 'Set-Cookie' string (got it from curl headers within PHP):

```
.SOMEAUTH=LONGRANDOMSTRINGDLSAKSD325KFASFCAK32LONGRANDOMSTRING; expires=Sat, 01-Feb-2014 11:11:25 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

A cookie is supposed to be created with

```
document.cookie = <cookie string data>;
```

right?

Everyone builds their cookies up with name, date and then that path=/ at the end as I see...
I have the mentioned string as variable in javascript. If I do

```
document.cookie = data;
```

where data is my string above, the cookie is not created (I should see it in browser resources right?)

What am I doing wrong? Should HttpOnly be there?

Thanks for any help - if I was unclear please ask for more info

Answer (score 0):

Remove HttpOnly and it will work.
Javascript cannot set HttpOnly due to its.. well nature. it is in fact http only.

Comment: I see the cookie got created, but unfortunately the 'session' is somehow not maintained, hm...

Comment: And it creates with HttpOnly as well? whaaat?

Comment: HttpOnly is used by browsers to keep data in your local computer about a site. this is created by browser developers to prevent client side scripts like javascript to manupilate this data. So you can not get or set httponly cookies. this restriction is there to prevent security risks.
I don't know what you're trying to do, but I do understand that its not what javascript intends to do.